# C++ reading data into a char*

Tags: c++, char

I am trying to read data into a char* with the following code:

```
void MyGameMain::MakeNewTileMap() {
    char* data[] = { GetLevelFromFile() };

    //failing at x = 0 y = 4
    // Set up the tiles
    for (int x = 0; x < 24; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 26; y++) {
            m_oTiles.SetValue(x, y, data[y][x] - 'a');
        }
    }

    //display level in prompt
    for (int y = 0; y < 26; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 24; x++)
            printf("%d ", m_oTiles.GetValue(x, y));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The function GetLevelFromFile() is as follows:

```
char* MyGameMain::GetLevelFromFile() {
return
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaabbbbbbbbebbbaaaaaa",
    "aaadddbbbbbbbbbbbbcccaaa",
    "aaadddbbbbbbbbbbbbcccaaa",
    "aaaaaabbbebbbbbbbbaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
}
```

When I run this code I get an error which in essence means I'm trying to read in data that doesn't exist, at the point in the second for of the first nested for loop, when `x = 0` and `y = 4`.

Can anyone explain why this is happening, what the problem is?

The plan eventually is to have `GetLevelFromFile()` to read in the string from a file so that I can store level data in separate files.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your return type on `GetLevelFromFile` is wrong. A string literal is a `const char[N]`. Pointing with a `char *` is asking for trouble later on (and is outright disallowed in C++11).

Comment: Also, this is kind of hard to debug in general when someone has manually count the characters. You should really really make it more comprehensive for maintenance.

Comment: You know C and C++ only have single return?

Comment: ok thankyou, so what should I change the return type of GetLevelFromFile to?

Comment: `const char* const*`. Then you can return an array of pointers to char, all const.

Comment: no, `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @Light: Only iff the Level can be modified. Not seen any evidence for that yet.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Slap a `const` on it if you like, but avoid `char*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you return is actually one string: the comma operator would in this case simply return the last "aaaaaa..." element. To achieve what you want (an array of strings) you should at least put the curlies around your array. (I assume this method is a dummy method anyway, because returning hardcoded arrays of strings in that way might be a questionable idea :) )

```
char** MyGameMain::GetLevelFromFile() {
return {
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
     ....
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
  };
}
```

UPDATE: and the return type should be pointer-to-chararray (or pointer-to-pointer-to-char) so that `char* data[]` would accept it properly.

LATER UPDATE: actually I'd rather had a dummy array as a static class member (marked as const if it's supposed to be a frozen value):

```
class MyGameMain {
public:
    void MakeNewTileMap();
    const char** GetLevelFromFile() const;
    static const char* level[];
};

const char* MyGameMain::level[] = {
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
     "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
  };

const char** MyGameMain::GetLevelFromFile() const {
    return level;
}

void MyGameMain::MakeNewTileMap() {
    const char** data = GetLevelFromFile();

    ...
```

Comment: you're right the function is a dummy function. What you suggested doesn't work. But you're right I want to return an array of strings.

Comment: A similar error the char* that is returned is just the first "string"

Comment: Right, because you had to adjust the function signature, too. See the update.

Comment: So the return type should be char**? because char* data[] won't accept at char**

Comment: Yep, actually g++ 11 doesn't accept both variants. give me a sec :)

Comment: Please go for const correctness, the strings and the array should be const.

Comment: A better solution would be to init the dummy data outside of the method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your declaration of the `"string","string","string",etc` is NOT declaring an array of `char *`. You are using the comma operator meaning the string returned will actually be the LAST line of "AAAA...AA" - which is only 26 bytes long, so you'll end up referencing memory out of bounds.
Remove the comma's and it should work as you want, because all the lines of strings will be concatenated into 1 long string by the pre-processor.

Comment: I don't want to return one long string, I want to return the whole things as an array of strings. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: the first thing I would suggest is convert from a char array into a structure (or class if you prefer). `typedef char BOARD [B_HEIGHT][B_WIDTH];` doing this will flag any issues at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct levelbase {
   int x, y;
   unsigned char operator[](_x, _y) {return (unsigned char*)(this+1)+_y*x+_x;};
};
template<int x, int y> struct level : levelbase {
    unsigned char data[x][y];
};
```

Better return a const pointer to something like above though.